# click a "next page" button after finding it with xpath - Python

Tags: python, selenium

the html of the button is:

```
<a href="https://www.metrolyrics.com/artists-1-1.html" class="button next" onmousedown="ev('Next Page');">
Next <span aria-hidden="true" class="arrow">&gt;</span>
</a>
```

I reach the button with:

```
pag = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/p/a[2]')
```

but if i the use `pag.click()` I obtain the following error:

```
File "......" in line...
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a href="https://www.metrolyrics.com/artists-1-1.html" class="button next" onmousedown="ev('Next Page');">...</a> is not clickable at point (635, 561). Other element would receive the click: <p id="onetrust-policy-text">...</p>
      (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)
```

and of course if i take only the link with `pag.get_attribute('href')` Selenium tells me that I cannot click a string.

what'Im doing wrong? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
    page.send_keys(Keys.END)
    try:
        pag = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='button next']")
        pag.click()
    finally:
        continue
```

You need to call this code to use the keys

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: the cause of the error is that the bottom of the page is not loaded can u try again

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.metrolyrics.com/artists-1.html')
sleep(3)
page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
page.send_keys(Keys.END)
pag = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='button next']")
sleep(6)
pag.click()` 

same error :(